# Conflict between mindmap and tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I have some trouble trying to put a mindmap graph and a tikz-qtree graph together in the same document. With the example below, the mindmap is all scrunched up. But if you comment out the `\usepackage{tikz-qtree}` line and the first tikzpicture which contains the tikz-qtree code, then the mindmap looks just fine.

Is there a way to put them together? Thanks. Btw, not sure if this is relevant, I will also use this in with beamer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,calc,fit,mindmap,positioning,trees,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree       % space is REQUIRED after every node!!!
    [.S
    [.A
        [.B [.C D ]
            [.E false ] ]
    ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}{mindmap}
\path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Start}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green] {
        node[concept] (A) {A}
        [clockwise from=0]
        child { node[concept] {C} }
    }   
    child[concept color=blue] {
        node[concept] (B) {B}
    };
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \draw [circle connection bar] (A) edge (B);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tested your example without problems with pgf-cvs and tikz-qtree version 1.11. I'm using MikTeX 2.9.

Comment: oh... I updated tikz-qtree to 1.11 and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Ignasi If you turn your comment into an answer (i.e. that this bug has been fixed with version 1.11 of qtree, then ceiling cat can accept it.) This will remove it from the "unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This wrong behaviour has been fixed with version 1.11 of tikz-qtree.